# How do I check if a column is empty in MySQL php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");

<h1>my recipes</h1>     
<?php
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {              
print "<p><a href='../table/show_recipe.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</a></p>";
}       
?>
```

Which command should be added if there are no user recipes yet?

Will the message `"No recipes currently exist`" be printed?

Comment: show us what have you done so far

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should always bind your parameters when dealing with SQL request.

Answer (score 0):

Make the recipe column "Null" by default.

```
ALTER TABLE `recipes` CHANGE COLUMN `recipe_column_name` DEFAULT 'NULL' ;
```

And execute the following query.

```
"SELECT *, ifnull(`recipe_column_name`,'No recipes currently exist') as `recep` FROM recipes WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"
```

So whenever any row is null in recipe column it will show the message which you have provided. Also you can use aliasing for that complete function.